# how to use Advanced Custom Fields with videos

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins, advanced-custom-fields

in this code, I have an Array of video ids and I use integrated vimeo videos on a page. The video starts playing as soon as the page is open and when the first video has finished, the second one starts. Now, I want to use id write in my ACF Fields.
    in first part of my code I try to see if he take right id that good. 
    but I have some difficult to change my code to use get_field(); with array.

```
     <?php                          
        if ( !function_exists('get_field') ) return;

            $value = get_field( "id_1", 300 );
            if ( $value) : the_field('id_1');
            endif;
     ?>

    <div id="headervideo" class="videoClass"></div>
    <script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

            var videos = [ '240466644', '146661000']; //Array videos ids
            var options = {
                id: videos[0],//first element
                width: 700,
                height: 500,
                loop: false
            };
            player = new Vimeo.Player('headervideo', options); 
            player.play()
            playMovie(videos, 0, true) 
        })

        var playMovie = function(videos, currentVideoIdx, first) {

        if (!first) {
            player.loadVideo(videos[currentVideoIdx % videos.length]).then(function(id) {
                player.play()
            }).catch(function(error) {});

            player.on('ended', function() {
                playMovie(videos, ++currentVideoIdx, false)
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ACF

```
$value = get_field( 'id_1', 300 );
```

JS

```
id: videos[<?php echo $value; ?>],//first element
```

Comment: thank you @Sco... I can let my code js an use videos[<?php echo $value; ?>] ?, how can I use array of id because here is just first element

Answer (score 0):

To create an array of IDs, use the Advanced Custom Fields **Repeater Fields**. Check documentation https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/

Then from there, it would look similar to this...

```
<?php

// check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('repeater_field_name') ):

    // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('repeater_field_name') ) : the_row();

        // get the sub field value
        $value = get_sub_field('sub_field_name');

    endwhile;

else :

    // no rows found

endif;

?>
```

Comment: but if I dont use Repeater can I do it with foreach like :

Comment: <?php
 $fields = get_fields($post);
 if( $fields ): ?>
 <ul>
  <?php foreach( $fields as $name => $value ): ?>
   <b><?php echo $name; ?></b> <?php echo $value; ?> <br>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
 </ul>
 <?php endif; ?>

Comment: I apologize - I find it difficult to understand the question.